# редирект с http вместо https на поддомен

Tags: ubuntu, .htaccess, apache2, редирект

являюсь новичком, но очень хочу научиться. 
вопрос такой:
есть домен, назовём его site.ru
есть поддомен, назовем его sub.site.ru
есть ssl для домена, т.е. работает `https://site.ru`
поддомен работает только по `http://sub.site.ru`
так вот если я ввожу в адресной строке просто site.ru, то меня почему-то автоматически бросает на sub.site.ru, при этом, если ввести https... то всё открывается нормально. 
хостится сайт дома, на ноуте. ОС ubuntu server 16.04
в конфиге site.ru в .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
Options ALL -Indexes
```

то есть никаких редиректов. в конфиге апача тоже ничего нет. 
Всю голову сломал, где может быть эта настройка редиректа?

добавлено 16.05.19
кеш браузера предварительно чищу. проверяю на 4 браузерах - опера, хром, мозила и ие. везде одинаково. 
ngnix не установлен. 
С помощью сервиса просмотра HTTP-заголовков веб-файлов я получил
    HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    Date: Thu, 16 May 2019 09:59:28 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
    X-Redirect-By: WordPress
    Location: http://sub.site.ru/
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Правильно ли я понимаю, что это вордпресс перенаправляет? но содержимое .htaccess я скидывал выше, там нет явного перенаправления. где ещё может быть такая настройка? в веб-настройках вордпресса нет такого редиректа

Comment: кеш бразуера сохраняет, в том числе, ответы с перенаправлением.

Comment: редиректы могут быть так же в каком нибудь nginx, который стоит перед апачем (если есть конечно). В файлах .htaccess в каталоге сайта. Или в php коде.

Comment: нет, кеш чищу. добавил в вопросе новые данные.

Comment: У вас редирект происходит в Wordpress. На это указывает заголовок X-Redirect-By: Wordpress Location. В wordpress есть функция wp_redirect(). https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/